# How to pass document id from one component to another component

Tags: reactjs, database, appwrite

I have created a document in one component and I want to use that id in another component

How to use the document id in another component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: provide the problem in detail, I assume when you pass on to another component, are you using second component within first?

Comment: Could you please add the sample code for the same? It will hep us to understand the component and give you the suitable suggestion.  Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how deeply you want to pass data, and what kind of data you're passing, you can use one of a few ways.

[Passing props to children components](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component): This allows you to pass data from a parent to a child component as a prop (think of it as an attribute). Beware though, this can quickly lead to unmanageable code if you "prop-drill" many levels deep.

If you have some state that is truly global, and needs to be passed several levels deep, you can use something like [React's Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) which lets you bypass prop-drilling. However, this can take an impact on performance if you're passing state that changes too frequently as it will cause all components that subscribe to the context to re-render, even if they don't use that particular part of the context which is changing.

For more performant state management you can use libraries like Zustand/Redux.

Some more context to your question would be helpful to better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the framework you are using.
just save the $id in a state var
or simply use the browsers localStorage api.
(localStorage is easy and can retrieve the $id value in any component thereafter)

```
async function createDocumentAndStoreTheId() {
  try {
    const collectionId = "[COLLECTION_ID]"; // your Appwrite collection ID
    const databaseId = "[DATABASE_ID]"; // your Appwrite db ID
    const document = await client.database.createDocument(collectionId: collectionId, databaseId: databaseId, data: {
      name: "someName",
      content: "some data for the user",
    });

    // Store the generated document ID in local storage
    // or use some state context API or something
    localStorage.setItem("documentId", document.$id);
    console.log(`Document ID ${document.$id} saved to local storage`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Appwrite error:", error);
  }
}
```

now you can call get item in any other component

```
let docId = localStorage.getItem("documentId");
```